# Entity framework update change

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity model with a self relation (parent/child). My entity named Article has a property called parent. This parent is in fact the relation, and ParentID which is the field in the relation. In ef 4 i did this:

```
using (var dbContext= new DataBaseModel())
{   
    ArticleTable newEntity= new ArticleTable();
   newEntity.name="childArt";
   newEntity.ParentID = 1;
   dbContext.ArticleTable.Add(newEntity);
   dbContext.SaveChanges();

  //after calling save I can do this   
   var parentName = newEntity.Parent.Name;
}
```

With entity framework 6, this doesn't work any more, I have get the entity from the database again in order to get the related parent entity. Is this because of changes to lazyloading? what should i do different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that in EF 4 entities were generated with piles of code that took care of change notification and lazy loading. Since then, the `DbContext` API with POCOs has become the standard.

If you want the same behavior as with the old 'enriched' entities you must make sure that lazy loading can occur by a number of conditions:

- The context must allow lazy loading. It does this by default, but you can turn it off.
- The navigation properties you want to lazy load must have the `virtual` modifier, because
- EF must create dynamic proxies. These proxies somewhat resemble the old generated entities in that they are able to execute lazy loading, because they override virtual members of the original classes.

The last (and maybe second) point is probably the only thing for you to pay attention to. If you create a new object by `new`, it's just a POCO object that can't do lazy loading. However, if you'd create a proxy instead, lazy loading would occur. Fortunately, there is an easy way to create a proxy:

```
ArticleTable newEntity= dbContext.ArticleTables.Create();
```

[`DbSet<T>.Create()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696136%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) creates dynamic proxies -

> if the underlying context is configured to create proxies and the entity type meets the requirements for creating a proxy.